# How to boost (double voltage) a sawtooth generator

Tags: boost, waveform, varicap

I have a circuit to drive, using a sawtooth generator, four varactor diodes (FC54).
These varactor diodes has the following specs:
from 2.5pF (at 15V) to 30pF (at 0V), but my sawtooth generator, based on an NE555 (feed at 12V) is only able to give a max Vout of 8V.

I was thinking to implement, to the sawtooth output, some "voltage doubler" (which should be adjustable, to not exceed a max Vout of 15V), or maybe a transistor.
The idea of using a voltage doubler circuit is valid or there is another better way to achieve the improvement? Some hints how to implement this improvement?

Thank you very much.

Current schematic:
[image: Varactor driver]

Comment: What does the rest of your tank look like?

Comment: @EMFields the following is the part where/how the tank circuit is implemented on the oscillator: http://s3.postimg.org/fc2d1kvwj/Oscillator_Detail.png

Comment: Now it would be nice to know where the base of the transistor goes.  Is there any way you could post the **ENTIRE** schematic and stop all of this cat and mouse nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest something completely different.

Have a close look at the LM3900 quad Norton amp chip.  This chip is similar to a LM324 in that it has 4 individual sections BUT: the op-amps are current-input instead of voltage-input.

Because the inputs are current-input, it's trivial to create a linear ramp by configuring one section as an integrator.  The difference in input currents sets the ramp rate and direction (increasing or decreasing).

Note that the ramp is a true linear ramp - not exponential as would be obtained from a simple RC network.  Also note that it is trivial to have separate adjustments on the rise time and fall time.  That means that you can have a slow sweep up (or down) and a very fast return in the opposite direction if desired.

You will use two more sections as comparitors to set the upper and lower bounds on the sawtooth.  The final section is configured as a latch to control whether the ramp rising or falling.

The main reason for suggesting this chip instead of a classic voltage-input op-amp is that it *is* so trivial to build what you want - with a minimum of components.

Start by building just the integrator.  Control the ramp speed and direction by modifying the input current to the inputs.

Post what you've done and we'll help guide you to the finish.

FWIW - one of the most successful building (architectural) lamp dimmer projects that I did many years ago was based on the LM3900.  I basically implemented a phase-locked loop that adjusted the ramp time to match the frequency of the incoming AC power.  This was essential because the system was powered by a generator-based power supply that had lousy frequency accuracy and really poor stability.

The main part of my circuit was exactly as I have described above - all I did was add some sample-and-hold stuff to adjust the ramp current.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. To get 15V, you want a power supply higher than 12V. Well, the NE555 has an output which can drive about 100 ma. Use this to power a voltage doubler circuit (2 diodes, 2 capacitors) and you'll get a DC supply slightly less than 24V. Searching for "NE555 voltage doubler" should cover the details.

Step 2. Use this supply to power a low-current opamp with a gain of 2 driving the varicaps,

Comment: I have done some attempts with LTSpice to simulate these changes. First of all: the following is the current (and right) waveform output of my current circuit: http://s17.postimg.org/lot67h7qn/Good_Waveform.jpg
Then I have done a simulation of your suggestion, but the waveform is wrong: http://s8.postimg.org/3vf7xzh45/Doubler_Output_Waveform.png
So I've tried to simulate just a transistor on the output, to increase the output gain: (http://s24.postimg.org/726qc2khx/Circuit_Transistor_Boost.png) but again the output is wrong: http://s24.postimg.org/dzeottkxx/2_N3904_Wave_Form.png
What's wrong?